# Is there a way to redirect ArcGIS log server errors to a URL/webhook?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I want to be able to log ArcGIS Errors when they arise to an external platform. For example, I have been using Sentry for other kinds of errors. So I want to be able to send the errors from ArcGIS to something like Sentry when they happen and I was wondering if it was possible to do that without having to set up a crawler or listener by ourselves.

So what I want is

ArcGIS server -> Encounters Errors -> Add Error to ArcGIS server logs and send it to a URL

Comment: We use Splunk and there is a forwarder and receiver. The forwarder takes the logs from //log/* and forwards them to the receiver. I don't see a way without some middleware to do what you want. One possible way would be to use python to shred (read) the log files, and then when an error is encountered send that error. You'd need to schedule a .bat file, that calls the python script that shreds the logs, to automate.

Comment: If your infra is in the cloud you could be in luck. In GCP I've setup Stackdriver to collect the AGS logs and send them to Logs Explorer where they can be filtered, alerted on, etc. Pretty sure CloudWatch in AWS can do the same thing. Azure surely has something as well.